# Is vitamin deficiency associated with hair loss?

Tags: micronutrients, hairloss, deficiency

I've heard some rumors say that vitamin D deficiency can be a cause of hair loss in humans, but I'm not even marginally sure about this fact.
I'd like to be better informed about vitamins' actions - if any - on human hairs, and not only vitamins D.

Some detailed but on-topic discussions and references to support the claims are appreciated.

Comment: There are vitamin deficiencies, such as vit A deficiency, which are associated with hair loss. If you are skeptical about online sources, you may want to include "site:gov" or "site:edu" in front of your searches to find potentially more reliable information.

Answer (score -2):

I point out two websites ([1](https://draxe.com/vitamins-for-hair-growth/)) ([2](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/best-vitamins-hair-growth)) which contain a plethora of references about relationship between vitamins and hair loss.

(1) https://draxe.com/vitamins-for-hair-growth/
(2) https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/best-vitamins-hair-growth

Comment: This is a link-only answer, which are frowned upon in all stackexchange forums. Links go bad frequently ("link rot"), and when that happens your answer will become worthless. So please quote the essential information and provide the links as references.

Comment: I know but @Acsor asked for vitaminS (not only D one). There is a big amount of sources and they cover exactly what is the topic of the question, thus I think copy-paste is a waste of time here. If you think my answer is completely worthless, I will delete it.

Comment: I don't think it's worthless now, but when a webmaster at draxe.com or healthline.com decides to change a link, it will instantly become worthless. That's why link-only answers are frowned upon. Your answer can become useless at any moment.